# Make full div clickable (html)

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I have the following problem!
I have buttons (divs) with a text hyperlink inside it.
I want this hyperlink to be clickable on whole the div. I got this to work by doing this

HTML:

```
echo '<div id="tagsul"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"       style="color:#FFF;" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></div> ';
```

CSS:

```
#tagsul{
width:190px;
height:40px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:5px;
background:#82e1a1;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

#tagsul a {
display:block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

This all works fine. But the text is now displayed at the middle top of the div. But I want it to be displayed in the middle of the div from both perspectives (height and width)

I was thinking I could do something with a top padding but this doesnt work since the whole #tagsurl is clickable so when I use a padding at the top there will be a part under the button that is clickable too...

Answer (score 1):

```
#tagsul{
width:190px;
height:40px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:5px;
background:#82e1a1;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table;
}

#tagsul a {
display:block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YuEua/)

Comment: display: block and then display: table-cell? why? why would you add 2 displays? o_O

Answer (score 0):

Remember to edit the height whenever you apply a padding. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options.  You can put the div in the href tag and style the div and it will be clickable or you can use the onclick parameter and use JavaScript.

Comment: hmm making the div clickable isnt very clean. Beside that the div style wont work in ie 7 and lower or something. the div will get a link border around it even when you try to style it.

Comment: Or use no link tag and us JavaScript to make it act as a link.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
#tagsul {
    width:190px;
    height:100px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background:#82e1a1;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    display: table;
}

#tagsul a {
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```